# Finding an angle of a triangle with three given sides (radian)

Tags: trigonometry

This may seem to be a really simple question, and the answer would probably be using the law of sines or cosines. But, let's say that you have a calculator that only has radian mode, how would you do this?
Specific problem:

[image: trigonometry_problem]

So point $P$ is a random point in a circle, which has the position of $(3,4)$. Using the Pythagorean Theorem or the distance formula, the distance from the point $P$ to the origin is $5$ (This may not be any use but I did it anyway). Now I want to find angle $a$, which can be determined by the inverse of sin cos or tan, so I entered the inverse-tan or the arctangent of $4/3)$ (opposite / adjacent), and the calculator gave me the answer in radian which is $0.927$. How can I have the degree of the angle with this information?

Please help ;-; thank you!

p.s. I was doing that in a coding language and it was in radian only.

Comment: $A_{deg} = A_{rad}*180/ \pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the relation between radians and degrees. An easy way to figure out how to switch is to use the fact that $$2\pi^c=360^o$$ From this we can see that $$1^c=\frac{360}{2\pi}$$ $$1^c=\frac{180}{\pi}$$

Comment: Wow, now I just feel so stupid... I multiplied the answer by pi/180 ... and got a tiny number

Answer (score 2):

Your radians answer is .927. You can use the radians to degree formula to convert .927 to degrees.

180° and pi are considered equal in geometry and trigonometry. Multiplying 180/π by the radians or π/180 by degrees will successfully convert between radians and degrees.

.927(180/pi) = 53.113°

So .927 radians is equal to 53.113°.

Remember these formulas!

Where r = radians and d = degrees

d = (180/π)•r
r = (π/180)•d

I really hope this helps!

Sincerely,
T. Smith

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. Sorry but the other person answered me first, so...